# transforming a useState to a redux reducer dependent on other value

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapping, use-state, redux-toolkit

i got a simple useState hook that takes  an id number from an object in an array of objects when mapping through it to display the data of that object as follows

```
const [itemId, setItemId] = useState<number | undefined>();

 {data.map((item: MenuProps, index) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setItemId(item.id)}
                className={` ${
                  item.id === itemId
                    ? "border-b-4 border-primary-200 mb-2 transition-all duration-200 ease-in"
                    : "border-b-4 border-transparent mb-2 transition-all duration-200 ease-in"
                }`}
              >
                <h3 className="text-4xl md:text-3xl md:text-center ph:text-2xl uppercase">
                  {item.title}
                </h3>
              </div>
            );
```

now im been trying to transform this useState hook to redux reducer   using redux-toolkit  but how to define the reducer given that it dependent on the id from the mapping function below was my failed attempt , i get squiggly line  under the reducer also for typescript definition which also im not sure how i can define it.

```
const initialState: DandFStateProps = { itemId: undefined };

const drinkandfoodSlice = createSlice({
  name: "drinkandfood",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setItemId: (state, n) => {
      state.itemId = data[n].id;
      return state;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

component:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setItemId } from 'drinkandfoodslice path';

const [itemId, setItemId] = useState<number | undefined>();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

 {data.map((item: MenuProps, index) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                onClick={() => dispatch(setItemId(item.id)}
                className={` ${
                  item.id === itemId
                    ? "border-b-4 border-primary-200 mb-2 transition-all duration-200 ease-in"
                    : "border-b-4 border-transparent mb-2 transition-all duration-200 ease-in"
                }`}
              >
                <h3 className="text-4xl md:text-3xl md:text-center ph:text-2xl uppercase">
                  {item.title}
                </h3>
              </div>
            );
```

slice:

```
const initialState: DandFStateProps = { itemId: undefined };

const drinkandfoodSlice = createSlice({
  name: "drinkandfood",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setItemId: (state, action) => {
      state.itemId = action.payload;
      return state;
    },
  },
});

export const { setItemId } = navSlice.actions;

/* Put the reducer in your store.js */
export default drinkandfoodSlice.reducer;
```